# How to compare List of Long and return the number of matches

Tags: java

I have 2 `List<Long> id = [2316, 2317, 2318]` and

```
List<Long> existingId = [1004, 1762, 1892, 1342, 1942, 2316]
```

I want to programmatically in java know how many did not match and what are the numbers, in this case 2 and 2317,2318

Programmatically, I tried the following, but it went to infinite loop with false always:

```
for(int i=0; i<webCrtIdListExisting.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("#########" + webCrtIdListExisting.contains(webCrtIdListNightly));
}
```

Comment: This question looks more  suggestive of a work order than a question. Please improve it by showing what you've tried and telling us what specific problems you're having.

Comment: Oops..sorry for my direct approach..I tried existingId.contains(id) but it always return false

Comment: You look to be checking if one *complete* list is held by the other, not if each item in one list is in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
     Collection<Integer> id = Arrays.asList(2316, 2317, 2318);
     Collection<Integer> existingId = Arrays.asList(1004, 1762, 1892, 1342, 1942, 2316);

    Collection<Integer> similar = new HashSet<Integer>( id );
    similar.removeAll( existingId );
    System.out.println("Different:"+similar);
    System.out.println("#of items that are differnt:"+similar.size());
```

Comment: Cool...!collction.addAll() can be used to do the reverser